# Elisp: referencing previous variables inside let

Tags: elisp, local-variables, let

I'd like to define two variables in let, one of which depends on the value of the other, like so:

```
(let ((a (func))
      (b (if (eq a 1) 2 3)))
  ...)
```

Obviously this is not the right way to do this, emacs says `a` is void. 
What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You should use `let*`

Comment: Next time please copy and paste the error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`let*` instead of `let`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html).

Essentially, `let*` is a shortcut for nested `let`s:

```
(let ((a 1))
  (let ((b (1+ a)))
    (let ((c (* 2 b)))
      ...)))
```

is equivalent to

```
(let* ((a 1)
       (b (1+ a))
       (c (* 2 b)))
  ...)
```